# Binary to decimal converter in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object-oriented, programming-challenge, reinventing-the-wheel, number-systems

This exercise with a test suite is from [here](http://exercism.io/exercises/javascript/binary/readme). I did not intend to use ES6 features, it's plain old JavaScript. That's why I seek advice more on the good practices, performance side, than modern syntax. Basically anything to make this code more elegant, without ES6.

```
// Constructor
var Binary = function(binary) {
  this.binary = binary;
  this.base = 2;
};

// Transform the string input in a reversed array
Binary.prototype.reverseInput = function() {
  return this.binary.split('').reverse();
};

// Handle the conversion to decimal
Binary.prototype.toDecimal = function() {
  var output = 0;
      binaryArray = this.reverseInput();

  if (this.invalidInput()) {
    return output;
  }

  for (var i = 0, j = binaryArray.length; i < j; i++) {
    output += binaryArray[i] * Math.pow(this.base, i);
  }

  return output;
}

// Check if any character is not a 1 or a 0
Binary.prototype.invalidInput = function() {
  for (var i = 0, j = this.binary.length; i < j; i++) {
    if (this.binary[i] != '0' && this.binary[i] != '1') {
      return true;
    }
  }
}

module.exports = Binary;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Flawed exercise

Before I begin, I would like to point out that the exercise is flawed:

- The task is not really converting the input from a binary to a decimal representation.  Rather, it is to convert it to *a number*, whose conventional string representation is rendered in base 10.  The test suite included this test:

  > ```
  > xit('11010 is decimal 26', function() {
  >   expect(new Binary('11010').toDecimal()).toEqual(26);
  > });
  > ```

  … which could also have been written as:

  ```
  xit('11010 is twenty-six', function() {
    expect(new Binary('11010').toDecimal()).toEqual(0x1a);
  });
  ```
- It is bad practice to return `0` for `new Binary('junk').toDecimal()`.  Acceptable results would be to either throw an exception or return `Number.NaN`.

### Review

Your `invalidInput` function either returns `true` or falls off the end.  Good practice would be to name it `isInvalidInput`, and have it explicitly return `true` or `false`.  Better yet, reverse the sense and call it `isValidInput`.  Even better, don't expose the validation function as a method at all — you don't really need one.

`this.binary.split('').reverse()` and `Math.pow(…)` seem extravagant.

### Suggested solution

```
// Constructor
var Binary = function(binary) {
  this.binary = binary;
  this.base = 2;
};

Binary.prototype.toDecimal = function() {  // <-- Method name is a misnomer!
  var output = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < this.binary.length; i++) {
    output *= 2;
    switch (this.binary.charAt(i)) {
      case '0': break;
      case '1': output += 1; break;
      default:  return 0;   // <-- This sucks, but the test suite requires it!
    }
  }
  return output;
}
```